# Не отображаются данные из Java код в jsp странице SpringMVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, crud

Есть код:

```
@Controller
public class FilmController {

private static final Film film;

static {
    film = new Film();
    film.setTitle("Inception");
    film.setYear(2010);
    film.setGenre("sci-fi");
    film.setWatched(true);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/")
public ModelAndView allFilms(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("films");
    modelAndView.addObject("film", film);
    return modelAndView;
}

@GetMapping("/edit")
public ModelAndView editPage(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("editPage");
    return modelAndView;
}
}

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
        ${film}
<h2><a href="/edit">edit page</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Суть вопроса в том, что по мануалу в films.jsp должен отобразиться список из контролера, но вместо него ${film}

Comment: https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/spring-mvc__modelandviews-model-value-is-not-displayed-in-jsp-via-el

Answer (score 0):

Решение заключается в добавлении в jsp файл:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```